# Browser skips "if", "else if", goes right to "else" statement

Tags: javascript, colors

Not sure if this has been asked before. New here and to JS. It is my achilles heel.

A quick walk through: As you can see I have placed the images in an array for ease of manipulation. I then told the browser if #assignments == image 0 in the index, the font should be color green and the same with the else if and else statement.

The problem is that the browser skips over all of the statements except the else. I believe that the browser is evaluating them as false and moving on until it gets to the last one which it sees as true and carries it out. This line of thinking leads me to believe that there is an error in the statements, most likely in the parameters, although I do not see it.

Start JavaScript

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  
$(function fontFunction() {
  var links = $('#splash');
  var body = $('#assignments');
  var backgrounds = [
    'url(css/images/violin.jpg)',
    'url(css/images/chateau.jpg)', //I own this photo. Taken at  Château de Vaux-le-Vicomte, 77950 Maincy, France.
    'url(css/images/museum.jpg)', //I own this photo. Taken at Peabody Essex Museum, Salem Massachusetts
    'url(css/images/creating.jpg)'
  ];
  if (body.css('background-image') == backgrounds[0]) {
    links.css("color", "green");
    alert("hello!");
  } else if (body.css('background-image') == backgrounds[1]) {
    links.css("color", "purple");
  } else if (body.css('background-image') == backgrounds[2]) {
    links.css("color", " red");
  } else {
    links.css("color", "orange");
  }

});

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="assignments">
  <p id="splash"><b>always create&#46</b>
  </p>
  </div
```

Comment: The console will tell you why `console.log(body.css('background-image'));`

Answer (score 3):

The url is going to be the full path to the image. A simple debug statement will show you that.

```
console.log(body.css('background-image'));
```

Use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to see if it matches instead of an exact match.

Comment: Well, the images are in the array, so the script is finding the images with the path given, however for console.log(body.css('background-image'));

Comment: So you did not try? `body.css('background-image').indexOf(backgrounds[0])`

Comment: Sorry about that, I had to splt to head to work. I did indeed use indexOf() and everything was as it should be. Output ->    ["url(css/images/violin.jpg)", "url(css/images/chateau.jpg)", "url(css/images/museum.jpg)", "url(css/images/creating.jpg)"]